# How to download source code of website

Tags: autoit

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <Inet.au3>

call("logowanie")
Sleep(4000)

Func Logowanie()
    Global $oie= _IECreate("http://pl.ikariam.gameforge.com/")
    Local $login= _IEGetObjByName($oie,"name")
    Local $haslo= _IEGetObjByName($oie,"password")
    Local $przycisk= _IEGetObjById($oie,"loginBtn")
    Local $serwer= _IEGetObjByName($oie,"uni_url")
    _IEFormElementSetValue($login,"<mylogin>")
    _IEFormElementSetValue($haslo,"<mypassword>")
    _IEFormElementSetValue($serwer,"s30-pl.ikariam.gameforge.com")
    _IEAction($przycisk,"click")
EndFunc
```

This code logs me in to the website but I don't know how to download the website's source code to do some stuff. Could you help?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29884151/4157124).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the source of a website using [_IEDocReadHTML](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEDocReadHTML.htm):

```
$sHtml = _IEDocReadHTML($oie)
ConsoleWrite($sHtml)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to download a single relatively simple page, the easiest way to get the code is: control-click > view page source. You can also get it by going to the sources tab in inspect element, which will also give you some of the other files in the site’s file structure. If you use this method, make sure to convert any relative links to absolute links in your downloaded code (i.e. convert '../../style.css' to it's full url starting with https://)

This won't give you everything, because code on the back-end is not accessible through any means. For a simple website though, there may not be any code on the back end and this will give you exactly what you're looking for.

This can be very finicky and will not scale to downloading a large website with many pages. The most robust way to get code from any website is by using dedicated web-scrapers rather than trying to go into inspect element and look at the “site sources” tab.

For Mac, SiteSucker is your best option if you don’t care about having all of the site assets (videos, images, etc. hosted on the website) downloaded locally on your computer. Videos especially could take up a lot of space, so this sometimes helpful. (Site Sucker is not free, but pretty cheap)

If you do want all assets to be locally downloaded on your computer (you may want to do this if you want to access a site’s content offline, for example), HTTrack is the best option, in my opinion, for Mac and Windows. (Free)

You could also use wget (Free) to download content, but wget does not have a GUI and has less flexibility, so I prefer HTTrack.

Comment: Despite question requiring details and clarity it clearly requests a solution using [tag:autoit]. [Answer].